# Unable to get the user session values in the joomla site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

In joomla, Assumption administrator is currently logged in.
**URL mysite/administrator/index.php**

i have printed the below code in the site/administrator/index.php.

```
$user = Jfactory::getUser();
echo "<pre>";print_r($user);


  [name] => Super User
  [username] => admin

  [groups] => Array
        (
          [8] => 8
        )
```

i can able to see the username, group, all values.

But this same code i have printed in the site/index.php. But i dont see any values in the $user

```
 [name] => 
 [username] => 

 [groups] => Array
         (
             [8] => 
         )
```

Comment: joomla admin login session and site (front end ) session are different

Comment: User should be logged in for values to show up. Secondly try using '&' when calling getUser(), e.g. $user =& JFactory::getUser();

Comment: @Shishir Do not use `&`, unless you want to get a deprecation notice. Objects are returned by reference in php 5, no need for `&`